# Need Help on MVC4 using ADO data Entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I want code to load data from a database which has two tables with a relationship. I want to display in a nested data view in **MVC4 using ADO Data Entity**.

Note that the tables have a relationship.

Comment: Please provide us the code you have tried and currently working on...

Comment: Hi! Welcome to SO, you may want to read about [SO How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [ASP.NET MVC Overview](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview)